# Relationship between ejs.co and embeddedjs.com

Tags: ejs

These two websites seem to both describe a very similar, Javascript-based templating language called EJS. But:

- ejs.co says the E stands for "effective" and has an active repository [on Github](https://github.com/mde/ejs).
- Embeddedjs.com says the E stands for "embedded" and has an archived repository [on Google Code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/embeddedjavascript).

What's going on here? Is ejs.co a fork? Are they actually independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, down the bottom of the Github repo I think is the answer:

> There are a number of implementations of EJS:
>
> - TJ's implementation, the v1 of this library: https://github.com/tj/ejs
> - Jupiter Consulting's EJS: http://www.embeddedjs.com/
> - EJS Embedded JavaScript Framework on Google Code: https://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/
> - Sam Stephenson's Ruby implementation: https://rubygems.org/gems/ejs
> - Erubis, an ERB implementation which also runs JavaScript:
>     http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.04.html#lang-javascript

So, ejs.co is describing itself as the documentation of the standard, and embeddedjs.com is an (older) implementation of that standard.